# Joining tables Yii 2 - MariaDB exception

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii2

Hello I am using the latest version of xampp which has MariaDB and when I am trying to join tables in yii 2 it says that I have a MariaDB exception. See the screenshot below.
[image]

What I am trying to do is to join schead and scstock via TrNo, see the screen of the database tables.

SCHEAD
[image]

SCSTOCK[image]

I am still very new with JOINING so I would like help in trying to solve the exception.

Here is the code for my join tables.

```
  public static function getFirstYearFirstTerm($currcode){
    return Scstock::find()
              ->select('scstock.*')
              ->leftJoin('schead', '  `schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
              ->where(['schead.terms' => '1ST', 'schead.styear' => 1])
              ->asArray()
              ->all();
    }
```

This is located in the in the ActiveCurriculum.php with the `tableName` function.

```
public static function tableName()
  {
     // return '{{%ccsubject}}';
    return '{{%schead}}';
  }
```

But I think I am not using it in this transaction.

Comment: Please share your exeception error screenshot..

Comment: It is in the first screenshot

Comment: I dont find any screenshots. I just see only your codes... :(

Comment: oh sorry about that, maybe it is not showing on your computer. I have uploaded it in imgur. Here: http://imgur.com/a/La8uV

Comment: I have no access to imgur. Just copy paste if you could???

Comment: I can't upload the pictures here. What platform do you prefer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122354/discussion-between-mohan-rex-and-quinlanlent).

Comment: ->leftJoin('schead', 'schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo') i think error on this line just copy paste this line some times work

Comment: it's simple remove ` from   `schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your quoting of the tables. The line

```
->leftJoin('schead', '  `schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
```

should read

```
->leftJoin('schead', '  `schead`.`TrNo` = `scstock`.`TrNo`')
```

or

```
->leftJoin('schead', '  schead.TrNo = scstock.TrNo')
```

It's best to stick to one or the other i.e either you quote all table and column names or you quote none of them.

---

An even better option is to add `schead` as a relation in your `Scstock` model.

```
public function getSchead() {
    return $this->hasOne(Schead::className(), ['TrNo' => 'TrNo']);
}
```

This would reduce your query to:

```
return Scstock::find()
          ->select('scstock.*')
          ->joinWith('schead')
          ->where(['schead.terms' => '1ST', 'schead.styear' => 1])
          ->asArray()
          ->all();
}
```

Comment: How do I add a relation between them? The problem with this code is that there's no explicit relation between the two tables, it just that it has the same TrNo, so I have no choice but to use leftJoin.

Comment: You can add a relation in code without one in the database. I've updated the answer with this information.